# Find and list all headers that have an ID included - jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

How do I find all `h3` on a page that include an ID `attr`, save them into an array, then output them somewhere else as a list (with the H3 as the value, and the id as a href)?  Preferably with jQuery, or possible PHP if not.

This is what I've come up with so far to create the arrays (I'd prefer them in a single array):

```
var ids = [];
var values = [];

i = 0;
e = 0;
$('h3').each(function()
{
if($(this).attr('id')){
   ids[i++] = $(this).attr('id');
   values[e++] = $(this).text();
}
});
```

So if we then had HTML like this:

```
<div class="headers">
  <h3 id="first">First</h3>
    <h3 id="second">Second</h3>
    <h3>None</h3>
    <h3 id="third">Third</h3>
    <h3>None Do not Show</h3>
</div>

<div class="headers-in-here"></div>
```

I would want the output in "headers-in-here" to be:

```
<li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
<li><a href="#third">Third</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all `h3` elements that have an `id` using the selector `h3[id]` (a combination of a tag selector and [attribute presence selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation)), and then map it to the structure you want. For instance:

```
const headers = $("h3[id]").get().map(element => ({id: element.id, text: $(element).text()}));
```

Then use that array to produce the content you want; perhaps:

```
$(".headers-in-here").html(
    headers.map(({id, text}) => `<li><a href="#${id}">${text}</a></li>`).join("")
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const headers = $("h3[id]").get().map(element => ({id: element.id, text: $(element).text()}));
$(".headers-in-here").html(
    headers.map(({id, text}) => `<li><a href="#${id}">${text}</a></li>`).join("")
);
```

```html
<div class="headers">
  <h3 id="first">First</h3>
    <h3 id="second">Second</h3>
    <h3>None</h3>
    <h3 id="third">Third</h3>
    <h3>None Do not Show</h3>
</div>

<div class="headers-in-here"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could do that in one step, rather than using an intermediate array of objects, but you specifically mentioned wanting an array. Here's one step:

```
$(".headers-in-here").html(
    $("h3[id]").get().map(element => `<li><a href="#${element.id}">${$(element).text()}</a></li>`).join("")
);
```

Live Example:

```js
$(".headers-in-here").html(
    $("h3[id]").get().map(element => `<li><a href="#${element.id}">${$(element).text()}</a></li>`).join("")
);
```

```html
<div class="headers">
  <h3 id="first">First</h3>
    <h3 id="second">Second</h3>
    <h3>None</h3>
    <h3 id="third">Third</h3>
    <h3>None Do not Show</h3>
</div>

<div class="headers-in-here"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```